# PyQt6 QImage.convertToFormat converts transparent areas

Tags: pyqt6, python-3.11

I try to convert an image using the code below, but I'm finding even the transparent areas are being converted (to black). How do I prevent transparent areas from being converted?

`convertToFormat(QtGui.QImage.Format.Format_Grayscale8)`

Comment: Gray scale images do not have transparent colors, so an alpha channel has to be converted into a color in some way. And what color should be used for transparent areas?